# How can I mute people's voices on Minecraft PS3?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

So during my first time playing Minecraft PS3 multiplayer, I heard people's voices coming out of my TV. This is really disappointing given that I want to listen to the note block sound I made, without people's voices interrupting the sound. At least on other worlds I can just mute the TV.

Is there a setting to mute player voice chat? Is it in the PS3 settings? I can not find it in chat settings.

Comment: Though I do not have an answer, I would recomend you also ask this question on the Minecraft Forums, since they would have information on the subject. Keep the question here also, so people can still answer to help you.

Answer (score 1):

When you press select you get a list of all the people in the lobby, you can then see who is talking and by pressing X on them you get the option to either kick them or mute them :)